# Variable inconsistently available in Javascript console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Out of curiosity, I started looking for a way to hack [this javascript-based game](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) via the console.

Looking at main.js in the sources, I could see a variable named Game, which provided access to everything. Yet it's defined in a local variable within that file:

```
var Game = {}
```

Here's the odd part. Some times I load the page, and Game is an undefined variable. Sometimes when I load the page, it's all available.

When it's not available, it's not under the list of keys for `window`.

I can't work out what defines whether it's accessible or not. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include full `javascript` code at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 the code I'm trying to use is in one massive file, main.js if you follow the link. It's definitely too much to include in the question. The code I'm executing to see the issue is just 'Game' in the developers console.

Comment: This game has one or two iframes if I'm not mistaken.  The Game global variable is only available in the top level document and should indeed always be available there.  When you got the Game var as undefined, are you sure you had the correct window selected?  It's in the dropdown list above the console.

Comment: _"It's definitely too much to include in the question"_ How do you expect an Answer to Question be provided?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm not sure you can have read the question.

Comment: @AJFaraday Yes, read Question. You have not provided a means to reproduce what you have described as issue at Question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @HaukurHaf iFrames definitely looks like the answer to my question. I hadn't been aware of that frame selector before. If you can express that in an answer I'm happy to mark it as correct.

Comment: There's a vote to close this question because it "does not have enough detail to answer", but there was enough detail, and it has been answered. Would it make sense to remove that hold now?

Answer (score 2):

This game has one or two iframes if I'm not mistaken.  The Game global variable is only available in the top level document and should indeed always be available there.  When you got the Game var as undefined, are you sure you had the correct window selected?  It's in the dropdown list above the console.